# how to send 2 values on javascript keyUp event

Tags: php, javascript, dom

I want to use javascript to compute values without pressing on the submit button. Using the javascript onkeyup event.
Is it possible to send 2 or more values from an html form to a javascript function?

This is the code for the loading of the necessary details on a table:

```
echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"ids[]\" value=\"$id\">"; 
echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"qoh[]\" value=\"$qtyhand\">";   
echo "<td><input type=\"text\" name=\"qbuys[]\" id=\"qbuys\" value=\"$qtytbuy\"  onKeyUp=\"proc(this.value)\"></td>";
```

I tried (which I only made up), but didn't work, what's the proper way of doing this,is it possible?:

```
onKeyUp=\"proc(this.value && document.cartform.qbuys[].value);\"
```

And this is the javascript that acts as a mediator between the form and the php file that computes the subtotal:

```
function proc(str,str2)
{
if (str=="")
  {
  document.getElementById("compz").innerHTML="";
  return;
  }  
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("compz").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","compz.php?qbuys="+str&prodid="+str2,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Although I'm not really sure if it works, since I'm only using 1 parameter for the function before.

Comment: Switching out of PHP, rather than echoing every line, can produce more readable code and reduce the need to escape quotes: `?><input type="hidden" name="ids[]" value="<?php echo $id ?>">[...]`.  [heredoc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) strings are also useful in this regard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I would [recommend using jQuery](http://www.jquery.com) instead of rolling your own AJAX interface. It's tried and tested and used by the giants of the Internet. Here's a simple example from the jQuery documentation adapted to your structure:

```
$('#compz').load('some_page.php');
```

That line would load any content returned by "some_page.php" into your "compz" DIV. So let's re-write your function:

```
proc = function(str1) {
    var str2 = $('#FormVariableThatContainsProdID').value;
    $('#compz').load('compz.php?qbuys=' + str1 + '&prodid=' + str2);
}
```

That way your PHP remains unchanged.

Comment: Or `function proc(qbuys, prodid) { $('#compz').load('compz.php', {qbuys: qbuys, prodid: prodid}); }`

Answer (score 0):

Comma seperates function parameters.

```
onKeyUp=\"proc(this.value, document.cartform.qbuys[].value);\"
```